# Checking Select value on button click, then firing command based on value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I'm trying to launch a command based on a select dropdown value. If the value is **Alabama or Alaska** then the page should re-direct to another webpage. If the value is **California** then the page is unchanged.

I don't want to check the value onchange, rather it should be when the user clicks on the button after the dropdown.

Here's the jsfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/41qpawr8/1/

I think this can be done in Javascript or JQuery but I don't them well enough to proceed. Thanks in advance :)

```
<select class="select-state" name="state" id="administrative_area_level_1">
          <option value="">-</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>

<button id="check">
Check
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `click` event listener on the button that checks whether the value of the select is either `AL` or `AK`, and if it is, we can redirect by assigning a url to `window.location`:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const locationToRedirectTo = "https://stacksnippets.net";
check.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (select.value == "AL" || select.value == "AK") {
    location = locationToRedirectTo;
  }
})
```

```html
<select class="select-state" name="state" id="administrative_area_level_1">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>

<button id="check">
Check
</button>
```